# is it possible to stop js code from executing for a limited amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know is it possible to **stop** all *js code executing* in the page (like when an *alert* pops up) then **continue** *the process* that was happening after an **button** is clicked?

Comment: checkout timing events https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve by stopping all JS?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

You can (maybe) write your code in a way that it frequently checks a flag, and set/reset the flag from whatever event you are talking about, but this assumes that you have full control of all JS code.